# Give section index without any section in table view in objective C for sorting single NSArray?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

means I want all that records from NSArray starts with 'J' when i tapped on 'J' section title in right side.

Below i give my code in this code i don't want any section i have only one plist 
  in that i store all the states in india so i now  i don't want to any section and when i 
  tap on any alphabet at that time sorting perform and all that rows which starts with that tapped 
  alphabet i want. i give example above and  code below

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Enter in numberOfRowsInSection method.");
    NSLog(@"returning number of rows in a plist.==%d ",test.count);
    return test.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"Enter cellForRowAtIndexPath method.");

    NSLog(@"Creating a cell..");
    //Create a cell

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    //The above line used to reuse the memory in a tableView only allocate memory which is displayed at a time.

    if(cell == nil){

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];    
    }

    NSLog(@"Filling Cell Content..");
    //Fill it with Contents
    cell.textLabel.text = [test objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    NSLog(@"Cell content === %@",cell.textLabel.text);

    NSLog(@"Exit cellForRowAtIndexPath method.");
    //return it
    return cell; 

}
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    NSArray *secTitle = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",
                         @"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",
                         @"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",
                         @"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z", nil];

    return secTitle;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"In viewDidLoad method");
    //Load from the plist File.

    NSString *str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"groupedTest" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str];

    NSLog(@"dict === %@",dict);

    test = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"statesOfIndia"]];

   //NSLog(@"In viewDidLoad method & Array fill from plist");
    NSLog(@"Array count(Length) starts from 1 not 0 = %d",test.count);

    NSLog(@"Exit from viewDidLoad method..");


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

In this test is my NSArray declared in .h file. And please tell me the  answer because i start learning before 5 days only so i'm totally new in iPhone and objective C.  Thank You Very Much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option in UITableView for this use case, implement the UITableViewDataSource  delegate methods 
`-sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` and 
`-tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:`

For customising section titles and supporting localisation,
UILocalizedIndexedCollation need to be used. You can read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalizedIndexedCollation_Class/UILocalizedIndexedCollation.html)

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title
               atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];
}
```

You will need to implement the below method to handle user touch on a section title

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [secTitle indexOfObject:title];
}
```

Comment: /* Thanks for answer @preson! but, how to use the above code i can't understood please read my question and in your answer i put it in my code and i got the same presentation in output but when i tap on alphabet nothing will be done so please help me teach me in simple way or give me example i hope u help me. */

Comment: Please make secTitle a property and set it in viewDidLoad, so that it can be accessed in the delegate methods.

Comment: But i'm not using any delegate method because with section it is automatically filter. and i also done secTitle declare in .h file (make it as property) and here i give you my .h file....

Comment: interface ViewController : UIViewController
    <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

    {
        NSArray *test;
       NSArray *secTitle;
    
    }


@end

Comment: and i also set your answer code in my code and i remove my --sectionIndexTitleForTableView method but it is not working.

Comment: Finally i can understand and i follow your instruction i understand that title gives the section title which is selected so every time this method is called when user tap on the any alphabet on sectionIndexTitle and give the index and title of the section index. so finally i understand and ya Thank you very much once again?